# Selenium unable to locate element

Tags: selenium

I have tried all the suggestions on stackoverflow but none seems to work. My code works for all other tested log in site but "https://internet-banking.dbs.com.sg/", which is the site I'm trying to write a script to log in and check my bank balance upon request.
My code is as follow:

```
def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://internet-banking.dbs.com.sg/")
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded)
print(driver.page_source)
email_field = driver.find_element_by_id("UID")
email_field.send_keys(*UID*)
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id("PIN")
password_field.send_keys(*PIN*)
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

When I run this, I am returned selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:...
Also, if I check driver.page_source, the result is that of the page.

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: I'm assuming the line that returns the `body` tag is the one that is failing. It's because the page hasn't loaded yet so it throws an exception. You should use Expected Conditions, specifically `visibility_of_element_located` and wait for the UID instead of body.

Comment: @MikeS driver.find_element_by_id("UID") and find_element_by_id("PIN").

Comment: @JeffC Thanks a lot. I try to return the "UID" instead of body tag and it works!!

Comment: Glad to hear it. I posted my comment as an answer. If you would, please accept it so that this question gets marked as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the line that returns the body tag is the one that is failing. It's because the page hasn't loaded yet so it throws an exception. You should use Expected Conditions, specifically `visibility_of_element_located` and wait for the UID instead of body.